# How to refresh finder window?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, macos-carbon, finder

I want to refresh icon for particular file/folder in Finder application.

```
FNNotifyByPath( (const UInt8 *)folderPath, kFNDirectoryModifiedMessage, kNilOptions );
```

`FNNotifyByPath` is not working for this.
Now i am trying with appleScript

```
+(void) refreshIconForItem : (NSString *)itemPath
{
    NSString *source=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Finder\" to update \"%@\"",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:itemPath]];
    NSAppleScript *update=[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
    NSDictionary *err;
    [update executeAndReturnError:&err];
}
```

but this function is also not working.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: have you found this solution? Please let me know which script is working for doing this. Because i used almost all the script but won't work any script. Any help is appreciated..!!

Comment: @Jigar you can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/15541439/944634. Finder refresh apple script is not working on 10.8 and above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check the value of the `err` dictionary after the `executeAndReturnError:` call?

The correct AppleScript syntax would be:

> @"tell application \"Finder\" to update POSIX file \"%@\""

EDIT TO ADD:  Alternately, you could drop down to the AppleEvent level:

```
OSStatus    SendFinderSyncEvent( const FSRef* inObjectRef )
{
    AppleEvent  theEvent = { typeNull, NULL };
    AppleEvent  replyEvent = { typeNull, NULL };
    AliasHandle itemAlias = NULL;
    const OSType    kFinderSig = 'MACS';

    OSStatus    err = FSNewAliasMinimal( inObjectRef, &itemAlias );
    if (err == noErr)
    {
        err = AEBuildAppleEvent( kAEFinderSuite, kAESync, typeApplSignature,
            &kFinderSig, sizeof(OSType), kAutoGenerateReturnID,
            kAnyTransactionID, &theEvent, NULL, "'----':alis(@@)", itemAlias );

        if (err == noErr)
        {
            err = AESendMessage( &theEvent, &replyEvent, kAENoReply,
                kAEDefaultTimeout );

            AEDisposeDesc( &replyEvent );
            AEDisposeDesc( &theEvent );
        }

        DisposeHandle( (Handle)itemAlias );
    }

    return err;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, its working fine. should i use executeAndReturnError: method or should i run applescript using NSTask?

Comment: I'd use executeAndReturnError:, or the AppleEvent way I added.

Comment: Thank you for AppleEvent code.  could you please suggest me some documentation for AppleEvents ? so that i can also learn this things.

Comment: Here's one: [Apple Events Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleEvents/intro_aepg/intro_aepg.html)  I don't know why it's marked Legacy.  The `NSAppleEventDescriptor` class reference suggests looking at this guide.

Comment: [How to refresh browser view in finder window(mac os 10.5)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9096277/944634)

Comment: This function is not releasing memory. when i am copying 1k files and refreshing the finder, my application memory is going 300MB. and its not going down.

Comment: @ParagBafna: You can see that the function releases all the memory that it explicitly allocates.  But it is possible that the first time you build or send an Apple Event, the OS might load some code or create a data structure that it never removes.  That's not necessarily an error.

Comment: tell application \"Finder\" to update every item in front window is not working in 10.8.

Comment: I have a a app bundle on my desktop. Its path is "/Users/noi/Desktop/noits.app" but this apple script code is not working: `"tell application "Finder" to update POSIX file "/Users/noi/Desktop/noits.app"` im very new to this scripting

Comment: FWIW- The AppleEvent technique has worked great for years, but under 10.13 High Sierra it seems to cause the Finder to delete both the custom icon and the FinderInfo attribute.  On the plus side, the Finder seems to refresh just fine without notification so with a quick call to Gestalt() the notification can just be skipped.