# How to refresh browser view in finder window(mac os 10.5)?

Tags: objective-c, applescript, macos-carbon, finder, appleevents

I want to refresh all `NSTableView` in `NSBrowserView` of finder on mac os 10.5. For refreshing icon view , list view and flow list view, i am using apple script.

```
@"tell application \"Finder\" to update every item in front window"
```

In browser view this script is only refreshing last column.

For example , this script is refreshing only third column(icns-copy.m.....).

[image]
Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only refreshing the last column because every Finder window has exactly one target folder at a time (whose content is displayed in the last column). The solution is to walk up the folder hierarchy and update the parent folders as well.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set t to front window's target
    repeat
        try
            update every item in t
            set t to t's parent -- go one level up
        on error                -- e.g. when you reach root
            exit repeat
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
```

This is a quick'n'dirty solution since it goes up all the way to the disk's root. Ideally, it would stop at the folder which is displayed in the leftmost column, but I couldn't figure out how to determine which ohe it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set view to (get current view of front window as string)
    if view is equal to "column view" then
        set t to front window's target
        set p to folder "Myfolder" of folder "parag" of folder "Users" of startup disk as string
        repeat
            if (t as string) begins with p then
                try
                    update every item in t
                    set t to t's parent -- go one level up
                on error -- e.g. when you reach root
                    exit repeat
                end try
            else
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end if
end tell
```