# Ctypes How to set OSType which expects characters but is defined as unsigned int (OSX)

Tags: python, macos, ctypes, core-foundation

So with CTypes Im tryng to convert this code below. It uses `OSType`, OSType is dfined as

```
FourCharCode = ctypes.c_uint32
OSType = FourCharCode
QTPropertyClass = OSType
```

We see here it is an usngiend character. But We see in snippet below they defined it as

```
const OSType    kFinderSig = 'MACS';
```

So in ctypes, setting a variable to `'MACS'` would not e c_uint32 type but it will be char no?

Please advise.

Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8895297/1828637

```
OSStatus    SendFinderSyncEvent( const FSRef* inObjectRef )
{
    AppleEvent  theEvent = { typeNull, NULL };
    AppleEvent  replyEvent = { typeNull, NULL };
    AliasHandle itemAlias = NULL;
    const OSType    kFinderSig = 'MACS';

    OSStatus    err = FSNewAliasMinimal( inObjectRef, &itemAlias );
    if (err == noErr)
    {
        err = AEBuildAppleEvent( kAEFinderSuite, kAESync, typeApplSignature,
            &kFinderSig, sizeof(OSType), kAutoGenerateReturnID,
            kAnyTransactionID, &theEvent, NULL, "'----':alis(@@)", itemAlias );

        if (err == noErr)
        {
            err = AESendMessage( &theEvent, &replyEvent, kAENoReply,
                kAEDefaultTimeout );

            AEDisposeDesc( &replyEvent );
            AEDisposeDesc( &theEvent );
        }

        DisposeHandle( (Handle)itemAlias );
    }

    return err;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const OSType    kFinderSig = 'MACS';
```

`'MACS'` is a character constant, not a string! This code is using a (questionable) GCC extension for [multi-character character constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944730/multiple-characters-in-a-character-constant).

You can reproduce the results in Python using the (builtin) `struct` module:

```
import struct
kFinderSig = struct.unpack(">L", "MACS")[0]
```

Alternatively, just hard-code the value as `0x4d414353` and leave a comment that it represents "MACS".

Comment: Thank you a thousand times!! This was driving me nuts!! A special thank you for two solutions in one! I love learning from seeing different ways doing the same thing, that helps a ton!!

Comment: In Python 3 you can also use `kFinderSig = int.from_bytes(b'MACS', 'big')`. ctypes data types aren't as convenient here due to the big-endian requirement: `kFinderSig = c_uint32.__ctype_be__.from_buffer_copy(b'MACS')`.